# NSOperationQueue: a sequence of NSOperation's with dependencies VS (maxConcurrentOperationCount == 1)?

Tags: dependencies, dependency-management, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, afhttprequestoperation

For example I have 3 objects:

```
NSOperation *op1 = ...;
NSOperation *op2 = ...;
NSOperation *op3 = ...;

[op3 addDependency:op2];
[op2 addDependency:op1];

NSOperationQueue *queue = ...;
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
[queue addOperations:@[op1, op2, op3] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

I could simply add all the operations in correct order. But for example if `op2` is cancelled then I should also cancel `op3` and I can't fully clear a queue in this case.

My questions:

1)Is it safe to combine such sequences of operations with `maxConcurrentOperationCount == 1`?

2)What will the program actually do if I swap around `op1` and `op2`? (`op2` should be performed after `op1` but the queue is able to take only one from the operations simultaneously)

P.S. In my application I use `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. Its inheritance hierarchy:

`AFHTTPRequestOperation` -> `AFURLConnectionOperation` -> `NSOperation`

So I can't simply take other subclass of `NSOperation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. It's safe to combine this particular sequence of operations with the dependencies you have given with `maxConcurrentOperations = 1`.
2. The queue will run `op2`, `op3` and `op1` or `op2`, `op1`, `op3` if you reverse the dependency order of `op1` and `op2`.

Theres nothing tricky in the dependency chain you've specified and `NSOperationQueue` can take care of things automatically.  You can only really get into trouble if you specify a circular dependency (e.g `op3` depends on `op1`), or you have an operation that isn't added to the queue, and so can't get executed to satisfy a dependency.

Apple has this to say about cancellation in [the NSOperationQueue class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html):

> Canceling an operation causes the operation to ignore any dependencies it may have. This behavior makes it possible for the queue to execute the operation’s start method as soon as possible. The start method, in turn, moves the operation to the finished state so that it can be removed from the queue.

All NSOperation subclasses should handle cancellation correctly by first checking to see if it has been cancelled and then immediately finish the operation without performing any actions.  If this isn't done then it's a bug, and operations may execute even though they have been cancelled.

(Interestingly this also applies for NSBlockOperation, which I didn't realise.  You explicitly need to check `self.isCancelled` in the block).

I used [CodeRunner](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/coderunner/id433335799?mt=12) on the App Store to try this all out and modified your program slightly.  It's reproduced below.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSOperation *op1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ NSLog(@"op1"); }];
        NSOperation *op2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ NSLog(@"op2"); }];
        NSOperation *op3 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ NSLog(@"op3"); }];

        [op3 addDependency:op2];
        [op2 addDependency:op1];

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

        [queue addOperations:@[op1, op2, op3] waitUntilFinished:YES];
    }
}
```

For a `NSBlockOperation` to refer to itself you need to do this, which is a bit disgusting but looks better in a `NSOperation` subclass as you can refer to `self`.

```
__block NSBlockOperation *op1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ NSLog(@"op1 cancelled=%d", op1.cancelled); }];
```

Comment: I agree with almost everything but wait. `NSBlockOperation` has `executionBlocks`. Should I still add check for cancelling when they are separate blocks?

Comment: Apparently yes, you need to explicitly check for operation cancellation even in blocks.  You can try it out yourself by cancelling an operation before you add it to the queue and seeing what happens.

Comment: If a queue containing the block operation is cancelled then it doesn't even start. You only need to check for isCancelled if doing something slow within the block like a loop.