# Saving a lot of data to core data causes app termination due to memory issue

Tags: objective-c, core-data, memory-management, nsarray

I am downloading a large number of items into an NSArray because I need to have all the items locally for offline purposes, once the Data is downloaded to the NSArray in the NSURLSession competion handler the memory usage of my app is fairly modest at around 120 MB, but when I start to loop though this NSArray to insert the data into core data and save it locally the memory spikes to 2 GB very fast and then the application gets terminated due to memory issue. I have already tried to split the NSArray into an NSArray of arrays to try and free up memory after each batch is saved to disk but this does not help either so I must be missing something. What am I doing wrong? I need to keep the memory foot print lower so I can get the data downloaded, and it is not an option to lazy load and only download what is needed etc because I have to provide an offline scenario so I absolutely must have the data locally.

In short

memory usage when completion handler starts for loop is about 120 MB
It then rapidly increases to 2 GB and app gets terminated
App is always in foreground

I am attaching the code below that downloads and saves the data

```
+ (void)fetchTillDataAll:(int)tillId :(int)startAtRow :(int)takeNoOfRows {  

    if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {  
        NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillDataAll:tillId = %d, startAtRow = %d, takeNoOfRows = %d", tillId, startAtRow, takeNoOfRows);  
    }  

    NSString *finalURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://host.domain.com/api/foo/bar];  

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalURL]  
                                 completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {  

                                     if (error != nil) {  
                                         if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {  
                                             NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillDataAll:Transport error %@", error);  
                                         }  
                                     } else {  
                                         NSHTTPURLResponse *responseHTTP;  
                                         responseHTTP = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;  

                                         if(responseHTTP.statusCode != 200) {  
                                             if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {  
                                                 NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillDataAll:Server Error %d", (int) responseHTTP.statusCode);  
                                             }  
                                         } else {  
                                             NSArray *tillBasicDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data  
                                                                                                           options:0  
                                                                                                             error:NULL];  
                                             if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {  
                                                 NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillDataAll:tillBasicDataArray count = %lu", (unsigned long)[tillBasicDataArray count]);  
                                                 NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillDataAll:tillBasicDataArray looks like %@",tillBasicDataArray);  
                                             }  

                                             AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];  


                                             NSPersistentContainer *container = appDelegate.persistentContainer;  

                                             NSArray *arrayOfArrays = [NWTillHelper splitIntoArraysOfBatchSize:tillBasicDataArray :1000];  

                                             for(NSArray *batch in arrayOfArrays) {  

                                                 [container performBackgroundTask:^(NSManagedObjectContext *context ) {  
                                                     context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;  

                                                     NSDictionary *tillBasicDataDict = Nil;  

                                                     /  
                                                     /  
                                                     for (id element in batch){  
                                                         tillBasicDataDict = element;  

                                                         NSString *itemId = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"itemId"];  
                                                         NSString *brandId = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"companyId"];  
                                                         NSString *languageId = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"languageCode"];  
                                                         NSString *colorCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"colorCode"]];  
                                                         NSString *discountable = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"discountable"];  
                                                         NSString *exchangeable = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"exchangeable"];  
                                                         NSString *noos14 = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"noos14"];  
                                                         NSString *sizeCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"sizeCode"]];  
                                                         NSString *taxGroup = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"taxGroupId"];  
                                                         NSString *taxRegion = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"taxRegion"];  
                                                         NSString *tradeItemDesc = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"tradeItemDesc"];  
                                                         NSString *withTax = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"withTax"];  
                                                         NSString *status = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"status"];  

                                                         /  


                                                         NSManagedObject *newPimItem = Nil;  
                                                         newPimItem = [NSEntityDescription  
                                                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TillData"  
                                                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];  

                                                         [newPimItem setValue:itemId forKey:@"itemId"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:brandId forKey:@"brandId"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:languageId forKey:@"languageCode"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:colorCode forKey:@"colorCode"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:discountable forKey:@"discountable"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:exchangeable forKey:@"exchangeable"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:noos14 forKey:@"noos14"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:sizeCode forKey:@"sizeCode"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[taxGroup intValue]] forKey:@"taxGroup"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:taxRegion forKey:@"taxRegion"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:tradeItemDesc forKey:@"tradeItemDesc"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[withTax intValue]] forKey:@"withTax"];  
                                                         [newPimItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[status intValue]] forKey:@"status"];  

                                                         if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {  
                                                             NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillDataAll:ItemId in loop = %@", itemId);  
                                                             NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillDataAll:newPimItem = %@", newPimItem);  
                                                             NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillDataAll:CoreData error = %@", error);  
                                                         }  

                                                     }  
                                                     NSError *error = nil;  
                                                     if (![context save:&error]) {  
                                                         NSLog(@"Failure to save context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);  
                                                         abort();  
                                                     } else {  
                                                         NSUserDefaults *tillUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
                                                         [tillUserDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"hasTillData"];  
                                                         [tillUserDefaults synchronize];  
                                                     }  
                                                 }];  
                                             }  
                                         }  
                                     }  
                                 }] resume];  
}
```

The NSArray split method looks like below

```
+ (NSArray *) splitIntoArraysOfBatchSize:(NSArray *)originalArray :(int)batchSize {  

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [NSMutableArray array];  

    for(int j = 0; j < [originalArray count]; j += batchSize) {  

        NSArray *subarray = [originalArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(j, MIN(batchSize, [originalArray count] - j))];  
        [arrayOfArrays addObject:subarray];  
    }  

    return arrayOfArrays;  
}
```

---- EDIT ----

I even tried splitting up the downloads into batches of 1000 records but that doesn't help either.

```
while ( loopCount < numberOfLoops ) {
            if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
                NSLog(@"%s loopCount = %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, loopCount);
                NSLog(@"%s startAtRow = %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, startAtRow);
                NSLog(@"%s records to fetch = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, recordsToFetchStr);
            }

        //[self fetchPricelistAll:(int)[NWTillHelper getPricelist] :0 :recordsToFetch];
        [self fetchPricelistAll:(int)[NWTillHelper getPricelist] :startAtRow :batchSizeInt];

        startAtRow = startAtRow + batchSizeInt;

        loopCount++;
    }
```

Comment: I tried using an @autoreleasepool as well and that does not improve the situation

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to split the Web service response to provide data in bits. You can download bits from server and save them as text files in documents folder. Fetch data one after the other from text files and save it in core data. Remove files once the save to core data is complete.

Comment: I tried loading data in batches of 1000 records but it still don't matter, the problem remains the same, there must be a way to free up the memory once each batch completes, saving to txt files sounds like a very ugly hack, after each loop of a batch size why is memory not freed up?

Comment: I see that you are concurrently saving all the data on to core data at the same time. What if you save one batch at a time on to core data. That will reduce the memory print.

Comment: it is saving after each batch already, each batch holds 1000 records and it saves in the background block already so I thought that meant it saves after each batch, are you saying thats not the case?

Comment: Based on my quick review of the code your 1000 records batches will try to  save simultaneously on to core data as you are using performbackgroundtask method.

Comment: Really? I don't think so the persistent container should perform each block in an internal serial queue according to other answers on SO and I am not getting locking issues

Comment: My apologies for using incorrect words. What i meant to say in your for loop is executing performbackgroundtask  for each batch. That means container is going off and creating private context for each batch. That means code execution is happening for all the batches at same time . indirectly app tries to load all objects on to the memory. You can avoid this by using NSOperation dependencies or using performWait etc..

Comment: ok I see what you mean so instead of creating one array and then freeing it, it creates 300 in parallel, ok so where do I put the queue and how? I am not very familiar with the operaionQueues, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: This has some leads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789734/nsoperationqueue-a-sequence-of-nsoperations-with-dependencies-vs-maxconcurren

Answer (score 0):

We can follow below methods

1. Call save method on context after creating 100/1000 records.
2. After save we can call reset method an context

   [managedObjectContext reset];